# How can I add a value to a FormMethod.Get generated URL in MVC3/C#/Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am added Hashed urltokens to my urls to stop tampering.

This is an extension method for Action:

```
    public static string ActionHashed(this UrlHelper urlHelper, string actionName, object routeValues)
    {
        bool generateToken = mIsSecureLinks;

        RouteValueDictionary rvd = new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues);
        if (generateToken)
        {
            string token = TokenUtility.generateUrlToken("", actionName, rvd, tokenPassword);
            rvd.Add("urltoken", token);
        }
        string scheme = urlHelper.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Scheme;
        return urlHelper.Action(actionName, null, rvd, scheme, null);
    }
```

So how would I add this hash to a FormMethod.Get generated URL?

Thanks hugely.

**EDIT1**

**In response to Chris's comment:**

I will check up "Html.AntiForgeryToken()" etc. Looks complementary to my approach as it protects forms POSTs and my approach focusses on GETs.

One of my issues was preventing users playing around with a URL like Report/List/{id} where id=CustomerId, and since this is a multi user system I did not want folks playing around to see if they could list reports for a client they were not authorised to see. All the functionality to allow them to query what they are authorised to see is within onpage hyperlinks etc. One could argue that GUID as primary keys are better than integers as less inviting. Also the other aspect to this solution is that the "protected" links will not work out of the vurrent browser context. Obviously there are links that one needs to work, and one just leaves these unprotected(without attribute on action).

Any thoughts appreciated.

Always trying to learn.

Comment: Just add as route param?

Comment: I added it into my action parameter list and it works fine. Thanks. Hope you like football :)

Comment: You also need a hidden field in the form ie     @Html.Hidden("urltoken","djdjdjdjdjdjdj")

Comment: Why are you trying to reinvent CSRF, when MVC already has built-in methods to handle this? Just use the `Html.AntiForgeryToken()` and `[ValidatateAntiForgeryToken]` combo and be done. This is really only for POSTs, and other atomic HTTP methods, but that's all you need anyways. Requests via non-atomic HTTP methods like GET are *supposed* to be replayable.

Comment: Chris, thanks for this. I have posted an EDIT1 as it got too long, in response to your insightful comment.